# Passing valid login credentials in Asp.net MVC Unit testing for valid login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I run this test in local machine and it shows (Test passed).
"alex" user exists in local database with "123".

my question is

**How I run this test on other server. Because I do not know the credentials.(alex user does not exist on other server) In other words how can I pass valid credentials in case of other server because or how can I perform this test?**

```
[TestClass]
        public class AccountControllerTest
        {
            [TestMethod]
            public void ValidLoginTest()
            {
                string domain = "sales";
                string userName = "alex";
                string password = "123";

                var controller = new AccountController();
                var x = new LdapLoginModel { DomainName = domain, UserName = userName, Password = password };
                var result = controller.Login(x, "") as ViewResult;

                Assert.IsTrue(result.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid, "Login in passed for user: [" + userName + "]");
            }
    }
```

**Note:**
I am using Asp.net MVC4, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

this is not unit test, but system test. [Unit test should not be dependant on the environment (database, cache, machine, etc)](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923).

For unit test you should mock your data.

For system test you could have some data-driven mechanism, for example using [TestCaseFactory](http://nunit.org/?p=testCaseFactory&r=2.5) and reading your data from config or external resources depending on the environment